# Please correct the sentence

Tags: grammar

**It would be a Hamas rocket heading over onto southern Isreal**

Is it grammatically correct sentence? 
For me the sentence should be "**it would be a Hamas rocket that is heading over onto southern Isreal**"

Comment: We don’t generally do proofreading here; we tend to tackle one issue in a sentence. Also, it would be good if you could list some of the research you’ve done on the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence as it is could be correct, but it needs more context to know. Here is a context where that sentence could fit:
A: "If there were a single thing that could completely upset the current detente, what would it be?."
B: "It would be a Hamas rocket heading over onto southern Israel."

Your version uses a relative clause, and the original version uses a reduced relative clause where "that is" has been removed, which is allowed.

Comment: It was a news report by Jonathan Samuel, i just wonder, "i saw her crying helped me understand the matter" that  i have taken from a conversation, is it also allowed in spoken English?

Comment: It's not grammatical as you have quoted it. You could  say "When I saw her crying, that helped me understand the matter."

Comment: Thank Jack, I'm curious to know, why previous one is allowed but it's not allowed?

Comment: @Edwin, the problem is that the sentence is not grammatical, that is, its pieces don't connect together to make sense. It isn't a single error. Where is it from?

Answer (score 1):

No. "It would be" doesn't go too well with the sentence since "would be" is past tense and "heading" is future tense. If you're trying to ho for past tense, try "It would be a Hamas rocket that headed over to southern Isreal." If you want future tense try "A Hamas rocket is heading to southern Israel." Also the word "towards" goes better in the sentence. "A Hamas rocket is heading towards southern Israel." or It would be a Hamas rocket that headed over towards southern Isreal."

Comment: I have downvoted because the question has been edited such that your answer no longer applies to the question. I would be willing to upvote if you change it to be applicable.